# MySQL query for filtering by attributes

Tags: mysql

I want to build a query for filtering products by attributes. Products and attributes are connected with intermediate table `_product_attributes`. Each attribute has group (like attribute `s` has group `Size`).

- If only one attribute is selected then only products which has that attribute should be shown
- If multiple products from one attribute group are selected then products which belong to one of those attributes should be shown. So more attributes are selected - more products are shown
- If attribute from one group (`Size`) and another group (`Color`) are selected then products which has selected size and selected color should be shown.
- Products count should be shown for each attribute
- Products count in one attribute group is not changed when selecting attributes from that specific group. For example there are 3 products in S size and 4 products in L size. These count should be shown if S size is selected or if L size is selected or if S and L sizes are selected
- Products count should be changed when attribute from a different group is selected (if size was selected and color then is selected products count for each color are shown considering products should be in selected size)
- If size attribute is selected in there are not products in any color, color attributes are not shown.
- If attribute from one group are selected, all attributes from that groups should be shown (just shown)

Here is the sql fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cWqvBYp6vMKy3KbNedeiqd/1.

Shortly, it is a simple filtering system. My troubled began when I tried to display attributes from the group an attribute is selected from. Like if S size is selected I want to show M size as well. You can see it fiddle.

Currently query shows correct result. But products count for S size is incorrect. I tried different ways. However it seems for me that it can not be queried as I want.

When making my question I omitted some details to make a question (which looks complicated) simple. I have additional `where` clauses on `products` relation (filtering by price).

**Edit**
The trick is where and how place condition for `where groups.id = 1`. It breaks products count all previous conditions.

Answer (score 0):

as you said Currently query shows correct result. But products count for S size is incorrect.

one way to solve this problem is you can use COUNT(DISTINCT _products.id), this will only count distinct values

```
SELECT DISTINCT _attributes.*, COUNT( DISTINCT _products.id)
 FROM _attributes
INNER JOIN _product_attributes ON _product_attributes.attribute_id = _attributes.id
INNER JOIN _products ON _products.id = _product_attributes.product_id
INNER JOIN _groups `groups` ON `groups`.id = _attributes.group
INNER JOIN _product_attributes pa1 ON _products.id = pa1.product_id
INNER JOIN _attributes attributes1 ON pa1.attribute_id = attributes1.id
INNER JOIN _groups ON _groups.id = attributes1.group
INNER JOIN _product_attributes pa2 ON _products.id = pa2.product_id
INNER JOIN _attributes attributes2 ON pa2.attribute_id = attributes2.id

WHERE 
 (attributes1.id = 3) AND attributes2.id = 6  OR  groups.id = 1
GROUP BY _attributes.id
```

Comment: Actually it works in my given example. But question is simplified (see my edits at the end). In real query I have additional products filtering by price. And having ` OR  groups.id = 1` makes my price filtering non worked.